# Is there a list or criteria of video sources that are deemed authoritative?

Tags: discussion, sources, youtube, evidence

I was surprised that youtube videos are discouraged. Granted that they are seldom pure depiction of scientific evidence, they are still very useful for natural occurrences (National Geographic) like behavior of cats (plenty of them).

Comment: Videos are generally discouraged on SE sites.

Comment: @Sklivvz Do you mean "embedding"? Or even linking?

Comment: @Alenanno videos are inherently subject to link rot, and are not SEO friendly.

Comment: @Sklivvz That makes sense. :)